# Rails naming convention for an action that shows a form and the other that processes the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I need to create two routes. The first one is a `GET` route that shows a certain form, and the other is a `POST` route that processes the form.

For example, I need to create a route that shows a form that allow a salesperson to unsubscribe a deal.

So, how do you go about naming these routes. Do you create something like this:

```rb
get 'deals/:id/unsubscription', to: 'deals#unsubscription'
post 'deals/:id/unsubscribe', to: 'deals#unsubscribe'
```

Or do you create a single route like that:

```rb
match 'deals/:id/unsubscribe', to: 'deals#unsubscribe', via: [:get, :post]
```

And put the logic in the same action based on the request method.

Comment: do you have `resources :deals` already?

Comment: I do have them. However, my question is related to specific actions like the example I provided where I need a specific logic and therefore avoid bloating the `update` action

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way is to just declare it as a RESTful resource which is CRUD'ed just like any other:

```
GET /deals/:deal_id/subscriptions/new # form to subscribe 
POST /deals/:deal_id/subscriptions # subscribe
GET  /subscriptions/:id # view with button/form to unsubscribe
DELETE /subscriptions/:id # unsubscribe
```

You can do this just by:

```
resources :deals
  resources :subscriptions, shallow: true, only: [:show, :new, :create, :destroy] 
end
```

This follows the rails conventions and uses the correct HTTP methods for non-idiomatic actions. For example `POST` is expected to create a resource which makes `POST /deals/:id/unsubscribe` cringeworthy - `DELETE /deals/:id/unsubscribe` is somewhat better.

And in general having a single controller method that responds to different HTTP methods is not the best idea since it has a higher cyclomatic complexity. Each method should ideally do a single job.

Each controller should also represent a single resource which makes jamming deals and subscriptions in the same controller a bad idea.

The controller is just your run of the mill nested resource:

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_subscription, only: [:show, :destroy]
  before_action :set_deal, only: [:new, :create]

  # GET /deals/:deal_id/subscriptions/new
  def new
    @subscription = @deal.subscriptions.new
  end

  # POST /deals/:deal_id/subscriptions/new
  def create
    @subscription = @deal.subscriptions.new(subscription_params)
    if @subscription.save
      redirect_to @subscription
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # GET /subscriptions/:id
  def show
  end

  # DELETE /subscriptions/:id
  def destroy
    @subscription.destroy
    redirect_to @subscription.deal
  end

  def set_subscription
    @subscription = Subscription.includes(:deal).find(:id)
  end

  def set_deal
    @deal = Deal.find(params[:deal_id])
  end

  def subscription_params
    params.require(:subscription)
          .permit(:foo, :bar)
  end
end
```

Comment: I like the approach. However, the code assumes that the deal has a subscriptions association, which is not the case. I'm still working on the Deal model. Do you still create a subscriptions controller ?

Comment: I also want to display an "unsubscribe" form. I don't see how you can modelize it in a CRUD way, unless you create a "negative" resource as you mentioned in another comment.

Comment: You are going to need a subscription model and an association anyways. So yes you would do it in a separate controller. If you need a seperate form just create an additional action. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`member`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-member-routes) route helper.

> To add a member route, just add a member block into the resource block:

```
resources :deals do
  member do
    get : unsubscription
    post :unsubscribe
  end
end
```

You can make it much better, if you process it through different controller as you see below:

```
resources :deals do
  resources :unsubscriptions,
            only: [:new, :create],
            controller: "deals/unsubscriptions"
end
```

Now create a namespaced controller like below:

```
Deals::UnsubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  def new; end # renders the form.
  def create; end # this process the form submission.
end
```

The above routes create nice readable urls for you:

```
deal_unsubscriptions    POST   /deals/:deal_id/unsubscriptions(.:format)          deals/unsubscriptions#create
new_deal_unsubscription GET    /deals/:deal_id/unsubscriptions/new(.:format)      deals/unsubscriptions#new
```

Comment: My question is more about naming conventions. So, do you think that putting the name (unsubscription) as the `GET` route and the verb (unsubscribe) as the `POST` route is the more common thing to do ?

Comment: Yes I am fine with this.

Comment: But it will be much better if you process it through different controller..

Comment: You're kind of on the right path but totally backwards. `new` and `create` in rails is all about creating a resource. A "negative" resource is a major WTF.

Comment: hm.. not sure what you mean here by negative resource.. :) @max

Comment: What really is a `unsubscription`? - its not a proper noun. It makes no sense at all to have a resource that when you create it it deletes another resource. Thats what I mean by negative.

Comment: Hm @max I am not convinced yet. But it is fine as people should have different opinions.

Answer (score 0):

Routing both GET and POST requests to a single action has security implications. In general, you should avoid routing all verbs to action unless you have a good reason to.
I think you can you different verbs similar in meaning to achieve the conventions as well as user readability and understandability.

```
get 'deals/:id/retract', to: 'deals#retract'
post 'deals/:id/unsubscribe', to: 'deals#unsubscribe'
```